# Why is this C# COM class usable from VBScript but not JScript?

Tags: c#, com, vbscript, ole, javascript

Consider the automation-compatible COM library in C#, given below. It follows a common COM pattern of having a visible factory coclass FooFactory implementing ICreateFoos which creates an object of type IFoo. FooFactory is the *only* coclass in the type library. (The factory pattern is particularly useful with COM, as it does not allow for parameterized constructors).

In the code below, I'm finding that I cannot access the returned IFoo interface from *jscript* **unless I make the FooImpl class ComVisible** (by uncommenting commented lines; this causes it to appear as a coclass in the type library). *There is no such problem accessing this from VBscript*.

That is, I can run this VBScript:

```
set ff = CreateObject("jstest.FooFactory")
set foo = ff.CreateFoo(0)
foo.Foo
```

But this *functionally identical* JScript fails, with the error "C:\temp\jstest\jstest.js(4, 1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'foo' is null or not an object":

```
var ff = new ActiveXObject("jstest.FooFactory");
var foo = ff.CreateFoo(0)
//WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(null==foo)
foo.Foo();
```

If I uncomment the line, I can see that null==foo is false.

Why does this happen? Is it a bug? Note that I think this is a problem is a combination of JScript and the C#/.net-specific implementation (possibly of IDispatch), because I have other similar COM servers - implemented in C++ - that do not exhibit this problem from JScript.

The problem goes away if I uncomment the commented lines in the code below, making FooImpl visible as a coclass - but I specifically do not want to do this as I don't want to expose implementation details. A workaround seems to be to make FooImpl ComVisible, but mark its constructor internal, which prevents clients from being able to CoCreate it, but that's hardly elegant.

I'm running on WinXP SP3 with Visual Studio 2005, .net 2, and have been able to reproduce the issue on a completely fresh install of TinyXP on a VirtualBox (both with Windows Script Host 5.7), and also on Windows 7 Ultimate using .net SDKs 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 (WSH 5.8). All OSes were 32-bit.

The library code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

namespace jstest
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ICreateFoos
    {
        IFoo CreateFoo(int importantNumber);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Foo();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class FooFactory : ICreateFoos
    {
        public IFoo CreateFoo(int importantNumber)
        {   // in *this* version, we don't use importantNumber yet
            return new FooImpl();
        }
    }

    //[ComVisible(true)]
    public class FooImpl : IFoo
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
    }
}
```

You can compile and register (you may have to run as admin to regasm) this with

```
csc /target:library jstest.cs
regasm /codebase jstest.dll
```

Comment: BTW - please comment if you have tried to reproduce this issue and succeeded/failed to do so.

Comment: Reproduced with VS2010 (C# express) and Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When QueryInterface is called against the `IFoo` object returned from `CreateFoo` for the IDispatch GUID it returns `E_NOINTERFACE` **unless** ComVisible is set for the actual implementing class.

When *jscript* prepares to call the `Foo` method it calls QueryInterface several times, including with this specific GUID, and since an error is returns it doesn't try to use `Invoke`.

When *vbscript* prepares to call the `Foo` method it does **not** check the interface supports `IDispatch`.  QueryInterface is called, once, with the GUID for IDispatchEx but it seems to simply assume IDispatch will be supported.

Comment: Note: vbscript is smart enough to realise that the returned interface (IFoo) extends IDispatch and so it does not need to call QueryInterface.  If the same object is returned as an IUnknown rather than an IFoo then VB *does* call QueryInterface with IDispatch'd GUID.